# Grunt Less task no output

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, less

I'm running Grunt on Windows 10 (using old console). All tasks works perfectly fine except grunt-contrib-less. There's relevant part of my Gruntfile.js:

```
less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          compress: true,
          yuicompress: true,
          optimization: 2
        },
        files: {
          "css/jg_shop.css": "css/jg_shop.less"
        }
      }
    }
...
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.registerTask('less', ['less:development']);
```

When I type `grunt less` the console freezes and produces no output.

Comment: What is the output if you run with `--debug` or `--verbose`?

Comment: Are you sure the file paths are right?

Comment: Ran with --verbose, all what I got is "Running "less:development" (less) task" in endless loop.

Comment: @RazvanBalosin yes, I'm sure.

Comment: Just to be sure, is your `css` folder right above the `Gruntfile.js` ?

Comment: That's right. `Gruntfile.js` and `css/` are both in my root directory.

Comment: grunt.registerTask('less_dev', ['less:development']); and try "grunt less_dev"

Comment: @venkat7668 It worked, I love you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the task less to less_abc and try grunt less_abc in console.

```
grunt.registerTask('less_abc', ['less:development']);
```